# YAML mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: yaml

I am trying to configure a YAML file in this format:

```
jobs:
 - name: A
   - schedule: "0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *"
   - type: mongodb.cluster
    - config:
       - host: mongodb://localhost:27017/admin?replicaSet=rs
       - minSecondaries: 2
       - minOplogHours: 100
       - maxSecondaryDelay: 120
 - name: B
   - schedule: "0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *"
   - type: mongodb.cluster
    - config:
       - host: mongodb://localhost:27017/admin?replicaSet=rs
       - minSecondaries: 2
       - minOplogHours: 100
       - maxSecondaryDelay: 120
```

The idea is that I can read the contents inside the job element, and have a series of different job configs which can be parsed.

however, [yamllint.com](http://www.yamllint.com/) tells me that this is illegal YAML due to `mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2` where `line 2` is the `jobs:` line.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

This is valid YAML:

```
jobs:
 - name: A
   schedule: "0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *"
   type: mongodb.cluster
   config:
     host: mongodb://localhost:27017/admin?replicaSet=rs
     minSecondaries: 2
     minOplogHours: 100
     maxSecondaryDelay: 120
 - name: B
   schedule: "0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *"
   type: mongodb.cluster
   config:
     host: mongodb://localhost:27017/admin?replicaSet=rs
     minSecondaries: 2
     minOplogHours: 100
     maxSecondaryDelay: 120
```

Note, that *every* '-' starts *new* element in the sequence. Also, indentation of keys in the map should be *exactly same*.

Answer (score -4):

The elements of a sequence need to be indented at the same level. Assuming you want two jobs (A and B) each with an **ordered** list of key value pairs, you should use:

```
jobs:
 - - name: A
   - schedule: "0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *"
   - - type: mongodb.cluster
     - config:
       - host: mongodb://localhost:27017/admin?replicaSet=rs
       - minSecondaries: 2
       - minOplogHours: 100
       - maxSecondaryDelay: 120
 - - name: B
   - schedule: "0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *"
   - - type: mongodb.cluster
     - config:
       - host: mongodb://localhost:27017/admin?replicaSet=rs
       - minSecondaries: 2
       - minOplogHours: 100
       - maxSecondaryDelay: 120
```

Converting the sequences of (single entry) mappings to a mapping as @Tsyvarrev does is also possible, but makes you lose the ordering.