# How to resolve yaml files by java(snakeYaml)

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I want to resovle config.yaml file, but I encounted some problems.
Here is my JavaBean Code

Oss.class:

```java
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Gavin
 * on 2019/11/15 21:06
 */
@Data
public class Oss {
    private String server;
    private List<OssConfig> configList;
}
```

OssConfig.Class:

```java
import lombok.Data;

/**
 * Created by Gavin
 * on 2019/11/16 9:32
 */
@Data
public class OssConfig {
    private String endPoint;
    private String accessKey;
    private String accessKeySecret;
    private String bucketName;
}
```

This is my yaml file

```
server: aliyun
  configList:
    -
      endpoint: "http://oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs1.com"
      bucketName: "<yourBucketName>"
      accessKeyId: "<yourAccessKeySecret>"
      accessKeySecret: "<yourAccessSecret>"
    -
      endpoint: "http://oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs2.com"
      bucketName: "<yourBucketName>"
      accessKeyId: "<yourAccessKeySecret>"
      accessKeySecret: "<yourAccessSecret>"
    -
      endpoint: "http://oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs3.com"
      bucketName: "<yourBucketName>"
      accessKeyId: "<yourAccessKeySecret>"
      accessKeySecret: "<yourAccessSecret>"
```

Test Code :

```java
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.TypeDescription;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor;

/**
 * Created by Gavin
 * on 2019/11/16 9:05
 */
public class YamlTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Constructor constructor = new Constructor(Oss.class);
        TypeDescription ossDescription = new TypeDescription(Oss.class);
        ossDescription.putListPropertyType("configList",OssConfig.class);
        constructor.addTypeDescription(ossDescription);
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor);
        Oss load = (Oss) yaml.load(YamlTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.yaml"));
        System.out.println(load);


    }
```

**Console Print:**

```
Exception in thread "main" mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'reader', line 2, column 13:
      configList:
                ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchValue(ScannerImpl.java:871)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:360)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:226)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingKey.produce(ParserImpl.java:557)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:157)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:147)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:224)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:155)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeDocument(Composer.java:122)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:105)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:120)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:450)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:381)
    at com.lew.scott.screencapture.YamlTest.main(YamlTest.java:18)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I read snakeYaml document,but I dont know Why can't it work?  If there is no hierarchical relationship, that will be resolved(but that is not requirement. I hope user can write more configs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YAML mapping values are not allowed in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313452/yaml-mapping-values-are-not-allowed-in-this-context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error yaml syntax, Guess what you want is

```
server: aliyun
configList:
    -
      endpoint: "http://oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs1.com"
      bucketName: "<yourBucketName>"
      accessKeyId: "<yourAccessKeySecret>"
      accessKeySecret: "<yourAccessSecret>"
```

[Yaml online editor](http://www.bejson.com/validators/yaml_editor/)