# E0000 mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

While running cloud formation templated I got

`E0000 mapping values are not allowed in this context`

Line number is `Properties:` where error occurs

```
InvokePermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
        Action:
          - lambda:InvokeFunction
        FunctionName: !Ref FunctionLambda
        Principal: sns.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition is wrong, as per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html#cfn-lambda-permission-action)

Action should be a string, something like below:

```
        permission:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
        Properties:
        FunctionName: !GetAtt function.Arn
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        Principal: 123456789012
```

Plus this is explained in [YAML mapping values are not allowed in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313452/yaml-mapping-values-are-not-allowed-in-this-context) as well.

So the correct definition would be:

```
    InvokePermission:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
        Properties:
            Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
            FunctionName: !Ref FunctionLambda
            Principal: sns.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Action: lambda:InvokeFunction has to be string you mean to say Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'

Comment: use a linter for yaml. for cloudformation[cnf-linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint)