# if condition with "or" & "and" in yaml azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to write if condition that satisfies below:

1. running axe analysis should be set to true
2. Build reason should be pull request
3. source branch should be develop branch (when the user select any other branch[ ex:release] axe should not run)
4. custom tag value should not be null

i tried with the below conditions

```
- ${{ if or(eq(parameters.axe_flag, true) , eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')) }}: 

- ${{ if and(not(eq(parameters.cust_tagName, 'null' )) ,startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop')) }}:

condition: and(succeeded(), or(startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop-map')))
```

Multiple if conditions are not working. keep getting below error

```
Exactly 1 parameter(s) were expected following the directive 'if'. Actual parameter count: 2
/templates/build.yml@templates (Line: 40, Col: 3): Unexpected value '${{ if or(eq(parameters.sonarqube_flag, true) , eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')), and(not(eq(parameters.cust_tagName, 'null' )) ,startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop')) }}'
/templates/build.yml@templates: (Line: 46, Col: 14, Idx: 1828) - (Line: 46, Col: 14, Idx: 1828): Mapping values are not allowed in this context.
```

first if statement with or condition works perfectly without errors when i add the second if statement with and condition, keep getting the below error. Any advise on how to handle multiple conditions would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show you full pipeline?

Comment: Unfortunately i wont be able to share the complete pipeline. Could you please advise on how to handle multiple if conditions. @KrzysztofMadej

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are adding the template condition (if statement) where scalar value is allowed - note that minus in the beginning of your if statement - which makes it non-scalar. Also check the error "Mapping values are not allowed in this context"

This is a common mistake in general YAML templates - see here

[YAML mapping values are not allowed in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313452/yaml-mapping-values-are-not-allowed-in-this-context/31335106)

If the full YAML was shared then it could have been better, as I am just providing solution on the basis of error message